# Linq complex object groupBy

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have fairly simple structure:
Each Customer has his **WeeklyOrder**.
**WeeklyOrder** consists of 5 **DailyOrders** and
in each **DailyOrder** are 5 **OrderItems** with **ItemType** (one of 5 slots basically) and **Count**.

I want to get counts for this week.
So I get all **DailyOrders** from all users for this week.

```
var orders = db
    .WeeklyOrders
    .Where(x => x.WeekNumber == week && x.Year == year)
    .SelectMany(x => x.DailyOrders);
```

Everything works fine, but now i don't know how to group daily orders by **DailyOrder.DayNumber** and how to group items in each DailyOrder (not all together, for each daily order separately) so i know the sum from all users - how many items of type 1 were ordered for Monday how many for Tuesday etc.

I am asking only for the correct linq query.

To give you and idea of what I want to get in my view:

**Monday**

- Item1: x1
- Item2: y1
- Item3: z1
- Item4: u1
- Item5: v1

**Tuesday**

- Item1: x2
- Item2: y2
- Item3: z2
- Item4: u2
- Item5: v2

...
etc.

Here is my model:

```
public class WeeklyOrder
{
    public int WeeklyOrderId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DailyOrder> DailyOrders { get; set; }
}

public class DailyOrder
{
    public int DailyOrderId { get; set; }
    public int DayNumber { get; set; }
    public int WeeklyOrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual WeeklyOrder WeeklyOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public int DailyOrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual DailyOrder DailyOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `orders.GroupBy(x=> x.DayNumber`);

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I can do that, but then i got groups of DailyOrders and I need to group items and sum count also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var orders = db
    .WeeklyOrders
    .Where(x => x.WeekNumber == week && x.Year == year)
    .SelectMany(x => x.DailyOrders.SelectMany(y => y.OrderItems))
    .GroupBy(a => new
    {
        DayNumber = a.DailyOrder.DayNumber,
        Type = a.Type
    })
    .Select(a => new
    {
        DayNumber = a.Key.DayNumber,
        Type = a.Key.Type,
        Total = a.Sum(b => b.Count)
    });
```